# Очередность загрузки классов в android

Tags: android-sdk, android, classloader, intellij-idea

Проблема следующая.

В разработке использую библиотеку (Б), которая в свою очередь использует apache http-client.

Применив ее для андроид (при написании unit-тестов), выяснилось, что по умолчанию грузится apache-http-client из SDK - его версия не совместима с (Б). Решил эту проблему, в Intellij Idea в Dependency изменил очередность зависимостей, поставив http-client перед SDK.

После этого все unit-тесты (Junit 4, не из состава SDK, также отдельно, если важно) прошли - грузились классы из либ, а не из SDK.

Однако, когда я собрал apk и запустил программу, классы загрузились из SDK и соответственно ничего не работало. Есть идеи, что делать?

Comment: @Evgeny  Vasin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать перенести apache-http-client в другое пространство имен при помощи jarjar.

Но лучше избавиться от библиотеки.